# UICollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath animation works weirdly with virtual keyboard

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit

When I call `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` method to scroll to bottom with keyboard-on,

```
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .None, animated: true)
```

I always get this strange animation.

[image: Weird animation]

It first scrolls down to the end, and scrolls up again a bit, and scrolls down to the end again. Why this happens and how can I fix this?

I checked this is happening in iOS 9.3 simulator.

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` shows this behaviour when its `contentInsets.top != 0`.
I haven't set it explicitly, but it's been set automatically by `UIViewController`. This can be disabled by setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property.

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Then the strange animation magically goes away. Anyway, now my collection view has no top space, so it renders badly.

[image: Badly rendered UI]

To make this to work, just set insets manually.

```
// collectionView.contentInset.top = 20 + 44
collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets.top = 20 + 44
```

But if we set `contentInset.top` to non-zero value, it shows the weird animation again, so you shouldn't set it. Instead of, we should try another workaround. For example, you can adjust `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset.top` if you are using flow layout.

```
collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets.top = 20 + 44
let flowLayout = (collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)
flowLayout?.sectionInset.top = 20 + 44
```

Or you can put an empty section. Or whatever.

Now it works properly.

[image: Good animation]